# friendly url htaccess using variable

Tags: php, regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Target is to create friendly URL, and I got stuck here.

My link below:

```
<a href="blog.php?id=<?php echo $id[0];?>">Turpināt lasīt..</a>
```

My .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On    # Turn on the rewriting engine
RewriteRule ^blog/([0-9]+)/?$ blog.php?id=$1
```

No problems in configuration, simple rewrite rules work. What's wrong here?
Thanks

Comment: How does the link look like? (View the browser source)

Comment: Your link should be: `<a href="/blog/<?php echo $id[0];?>">Turpināt lasīt..</a>`

Comment: current source http://localhost/blog/blog.php?id=7 and using anubhava link helps - source is good but leads to 404 :(

Comment: so your issue resolved right?

Comment: not really, rewrite rule does not work, link leads not found, but i want it to lead blog.php?id=$1as mentioned in .htaccess

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok try this code:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+blog\.php\?id=([^\s&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /blog/%1? [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^blog/([0-9]+)/?$ /blog.php?id=$1 [L,QSA]
```